nodejs Dockerfile puppeteer como dependencia
les consulto , porque en un servidor nodejs, agregue una ruta para crear imagenes con puppeter. Y al agregar esa ruta, tengo que hacer las modificaciones necesarias para que puppeter funcione. tengo esta version    "puppeteer": "^23.6.0" en mi package.json .
he probado algunas maneras,
FROM node:18-slim
  # Instalar dependencias necesarias
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      wget \
      gnupg \
      bzip2 \
      fonts-liberation \
      libappindicator3-1 \
      libasound2 \
      libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
      libatk1.0-0 \
      libcups2 \
      libdbus-1-3 \
      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
      libnspr4 \
      libnss3 \
      libx11-xcb1 \
      libxcomposite1 \
      libxcursor1 \
      libxdamage1 \
      libxrandr2 \
      libxss1 \
      libxtst6 \
      libgbm1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

  # Create a user with name 'app' and group that will be used to run the app
  RUN groupadd -r app && useradd -rm -g app -G audio,video app

  # Establecer el directorio de trabajo
  WORKDIR /home/app

  # Copiar archivos de configuración y dependencias
  COPY package*.json ./

  # Limpiar caché de npm y luego instalar dependencias
  RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install

  # Copiar el resto de la aplicación
  COPY . .

  # Instalar PM2 globalmente
  RUN npm install -g pm2

  # Exponer el puerto que usará tu aplicación
  EXPOSE 5200

  # Give app user access to all the project folder
  RUN chown -R app:app /home/app

  RUN chmod -R 777 /home/app

  USER app
  # Comando para iniciar la aplicación al ejecutar el contenedor
  CMD ["pm2-runtime", "dist/src/app.js"]


con este Dockerfile me da este error cuando esjecuto esa ruta en particular
Server running at http://localhost:5200...
Error al generar la imagen: Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 130.0.6723.91). This can occur if either

you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npx puppeteer browsers install chrome) or

your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/app/.cache/puppeteer).


For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/home/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/node/BrowserLauncher.ts:466:17)

at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/home/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/node/ChromeLauncher.ts:279:19)

at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/home/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/node/ChromeLauncher.ts:130:31)

at ChromeLauncher.launch (/home/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/node/BrowserLauncher.ts:100:24)

at createFile (/home/app/src/controllers/convert.ts:25:25)

